# Result of invalid iterator passed to std::unordered_set::erase()

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

std::unordered_set::erase() has 3 overloads: In the one taking a reference, passing an "invalid" value, i.e. one that doesn't exist in the set, simply makes erase() return 0. But what about the other two overloads?

Does the C++11 standard say what erase() should do in this case, or it's compiler dependent? Is it supposed to return end() or undefined behavior?

I couldn't find an answer in the specification, cppreference.com, cplusplus.com. On IBM site they say it returns end() if no element remains after the operation, but what happens if the operation itself fails due to an invalid iterator?

And in general, do erase() methods for STL containers simply have undefined behavior in these case?
(so I need to check my iterators before I pass any to erase(), or use the unordered_set::erase() overload which takes a value_type reference, which would simply return 0 if it fails)

Comment: If you're dealing with an invalid iterator, you've already made an error somewhere else. The standard library doesn't care. Why should it? It only gives you access to valid iterators - anything you do afterwards is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two completely different cases. There is no "invalid value", values that don't exist in the set are still valid. So you pass a valid value that s not contained in the set and thus get 0 returned - no elements have been erased.

The other overloads are completely different. The standard requires the iterators passed to the erase methods to be "valid and dereferencable" and "a valid iterator range", respectively. Otherwise the behavior is undefined.

So yes, iterators have to be valid. But you cannot check if an iterator is valid programmatically - you have to make sure from your program logic, that they are.

Answer (score 4):

There is a big semantic difference between trying to remove a value that doesn't occur in set and trying to erase from a invalid iterator.

Trying to use an invalid iterator is undefined behaviour and will end badly.

Do you have a specific use-case you are thinking of when you might want to erase an invalid iterator?

Comment: No, but I want to know what to expect. Is there any defined behavior, e.g. "nothing changes", for cases like "remove using invalid iterator" or "remove using valid iterator which points to a value in another container"?

Comment: I want to know what to expect, so that my code can use assert() to catch everything invalid it can detect

Comment: No. Like 111111's answer says, invalid iterators passed to `erase` result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @us2012 Even if it's a valid iterator pointing to some other container? I want to know if it's guaranteed erase() does nothing, or any destructuve result is possible AKA undefined behavior

Comment: "know what to expect" you can't expect anything, that's why it's undefined. A likely outcome is 1. nothing will happen 2. the container will be corrupted 3. your program will explode. I suggest you making a build ensuring that you have stdlib asserts on they will hopefully asser on these sorts of things: (for GCC, `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` should be defined).

Comment: @fr33domlover using another container of the same types iterator is a fast track to a segfault. it's a common copy and paste bug.

Comment: @fr33domlover Iterator to other container results in undefined behaviour too. Worse, in my humble opinion the sole possibility of an iterator to another container being passed to `erase` shows that there are very serious design flaws in your code.

Comment: PS: read undefined behaviour as "using this is a bug" not "something good might happen"

Comment: I don't think you all understand. I don't pass any iterator to any erase() methods. At all. But someone else will use the interface I'm writing, and I want my methods to be able to detect invalid values. For example, if I call erase() with an iterator, I can use find() first to make sure the iterator points to the right container. It doesn't cover invalid iterators, but it does detect the case of a valid-iterator-of-some-other-container. This way I help the user detect errors and safely make assumptions in my code (allowing it to avoid some tests and become faster when it's critical)